# AWS Amplify for Android - GraphQL API and Database

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I am following the AWS Android Amplify module 5 API and Database implementation guide but I encountered an error where I am unable to build the project due to unresolved symbols in the NoteData.java file which is automatically generated by Amplify representing my data schema.

Upon inspecting the ModelConfig.java file, I realized that the parameters for both "type" and "version" were not implemented in the ModelConfig.java. Are these parameters necessary and should they be deleted?

```
package com.amplifyframework.core.model.annotations;

import com.amplifyframework.core.model.Model;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

/**
 * {@link ModelConfig} annotates any {@link Model} with applicable configuration information.
 *
 * The {@link RetentionPolicy#RUNTIME} annotation is added to
 * retain {@link ModelConfig} at runtime for the reflection capabilities to work
 * in order to check if this annotation is present for a field of a Model.
 *
 * {@link ElementType#TYPE} annotation is added to indicate
 * {@link ModelConfig} annotation can be used only on types (class, interface, enum).
 */
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface ModelConfig {
    /**
     * Specifies the plural version of the model name.
     * @return the plural version of the name.
     */
    String pluralName() default "";

    /**
     * Specifies an array of authorization rules that should apply to this {@link Model}.
     * @return list of {@link AuthRule} annotations.
     */
    AuthRule[] authRules() default {};
}
```

```
import static com.amplifyframework.core.model.query.predicate.QueryField.field;

/** This is an auto generated class representing the NoteData type in your schema. */
@SuppressWarnings("all")
@ModelConfig(pluralName = "NoteData", type = Model.Type.USER, version = 1, authRules = {
  @AuthRule(allow = AuthStrategy.OWNER, ownerField = "owner", identityClaim = "cognito:username", provider = "userPools", operations = { ModelOperation.CREATE, ModelOperation.UPDATE, ModelOperation.DELETE, ModelOperation.READ })
})
```

[NoteData.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlJTL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, It seems to work without the parameters. I can remove the 2 parameters m type and version. It works just fine.

You should be following the ModelConfig.java file's implementation.

https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/generate-model/q/integration/android/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `targetNames` parameter for `@BelongsTo` (on the amplify generated model) hasn't been implemented too. Discarding the parameter should work fine as well.